# How to draw dotted gridlayout cell border using swing?

Tags: swing

When i am declaring rows and columns to my gridlayout.eg: 3x2 (3 rows and 2 cols).I have to get a skeletal view of these rows and columns.Like a dotted rectangles.How can we achieve this by using swing ?

regards
Mathan

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Border](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/GUI/Swing1/Magercises/M5/index.html) to each of your components in the gridlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass a JPanel to draw a grid within paintChildren(). Any components you add to this panel will show this grid. For example:

```
public class DebugPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
        super.paintChildren(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        // dashed stroke
        BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 1,new float[]{5},0);
        ((Graphics2D)g).setStroke(stroke);      
        drawComponentGrid(this,g);
    }

    /**
     * Drawn vertical and horizontal guides for a containers child 
     * components
     */
    private static void drawComponentGrid(Container c, Graphics g) {
        for(int i=0;i<c.getComponentCount();++i) {
            Rectangle r = c.getComponent(i).getBounds();
            int x = r.x;
            // vertical line at left edge of component
            g.drawLine(x,0,x,c.getHeight());
            x+= r.width;
            // vertical line at right edge of component
            g.drawLine(x,0,x,c.getHeight());

            // horizontal line at top of component
            int y = r.y;
            g.drawLine(0,y,c.getWidth(),y);
            // horizontal line at bottom of component
            y+= r.height;
            g.drawLine(0,y,c.getWidth(),y);
        }
    }
}
```